# SVG Rect Rotation

Tags: svg, rotation, transformation

I want to do apply a rotation to a rect element in svg, such that the two ends of the rect however are excluded from the rotation. The following image should depict what I mean by that:

the first rect will look like the third one after a normal rotation. What I want however is the second one where the two left right ends of the rect are not touch on their vertical axis. What is best way to achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: that's not a rotation at all, it's a skew. SVG has a [simplified way to create a skew transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace).